# SQLSTATE[HY093] - Basic insert to database

Tags: php, pdo

When I try to insert somethings to my database I get these warnings.

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in
```

I am just doing an insert into the database, without complex functions.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into `students`(`name`, `surname`, `username`, `password`, `date_of_birth`) VALUES(:name, :surname, :username, :password, :date_of_birth)");

$query->execute(array(
":name" => $name,
":surname" => $surname,
":username" => $username,
":date_of_birth" => $date_of_birth));
```

Type in database is set right.

When I try return values of variables, everything returns correct.

Comment: You have 5 parameters but 4 inputs.

Comment: Yeah you're missing the password input.

Comment: password is missing